# Variable-sized object may not be initialized Error despite initialization

Tags: c++

```
int main(){
    int sample_rate = 50;

    int t_max = 60*5 ;

    int dimensions = 3;
    int num_samples = sample_rate * t_max;

    double data[dimensions][num_samples] = { { } }; //Error here
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that the size of an array on the heap must be known during compile time which it is here (3 x 15000). Why am I still getting the error?

Comment: You should copy-paste the exact compilation instruction you do and the exact error you get, because it could be different for other people with different compilers or who use different compiler options.

Comment: Mark those four `int` variables as `const int`.

Comment: @PeteBecker solved it, thanks

Comment: `I understand that the size of an array on the heap must be known during compile time` This array is on the stack.

Comment: @tkausl — and it’s arrays on the **stack** that have to have their size known at compile time.

Comment: If you are using c++11, you should opt for `constexpr`

Comment: To those saying its on the stack, of course you're right. My mistake. @TheoWalton I will look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bound (size) of an array when it is specified has to be a constant-expression as per [[dcl.array]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.array#1).
The bounds you have specified are not constant expressions. To convert them into such, you either have to prepend `const` or `constexpr` (C++11 onward) before the declaration of those four integers like this:

```
const int sample_rate = 50;
```

Or

```
constexpr int sample_rate = 50;
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use `std::vector` instead.

```
#include <vector>

int main(){
    int sample_rate = 50;

    int t_max = 60*5 ;

    int dimensions = 3;
    int num_samples = sample_rate * t_max;

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> data(dimensions, std::vector<double>(num_samples));
    // access data like this
    data[0][0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although this answer is extremely helpful and I will do what you suggested, it is not the answer to my question so I can't accept it, but take my upvote.